# Load more AJAX on WP Query

Tags: wp-query, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get an AJAX WP Query loop to output 2 posts then use a 'Load more' button to load the next page of results. What is the best method to approach as not currently working?

**JS**

```
  var ajaxRequest=function(){
  var filter = $('#filter');
  var page = 1; // What page we are on.
  var ppp = 3; // Post per page
        $.ajax({
            url: filter.attr('action'),
            data: filter.serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
            ppp: ppp,
            success: function(response) {
              page++;
              $(".card-wrap").append(response); //Post class
              $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
            }
        });
    };
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json"); //Outputting as JSON for map data.
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];    
    $args = array(
        'order' => $_POST['date'],
        'post_type' => 'custom',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'offset' => $offset,        
    );
    [Rest of query]
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>
```

Comment: Check out https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to use ajax in wordpress you must have to follow these step:
1) first make your js file like main.js.

2) localize it in functions.php with `wp_localize_script()`.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main.js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js', array( 'jquery'  ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'main.js', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
```

3) make your javascript or jquery code to run your query with ajax and in ajax data object add a action property like action: 'load_more_posts'.
This action property will make function with same name to excute our code.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#load_more_posts').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('hi');
        e.preventDefault();
         var $offset = $(this).data('offset');
         console.log('var'+$offset);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type: 'JSON',
            data: {
                offset: $offset,
                action: 'load_more_posts'
            },
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $('#load_more_posts').data('offset', parseInt(response.data.offset));

            }
        }); 
    })
});
```

4) In functions.php

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts' );
    function load_more_posts(){
        global $post;
        $args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page'=> 2, 'offset'=> $_POST['offset']);
        $rst=[];
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if($query->have_posts()):
            while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
                $rst[] = $post;
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            $offset = $_POST['offset']+2;
        endif;
        wp_send_json_success(array('post'=>$rst, 'offset'=>$offset));
    }
```

wp_ajax_nopriv_(action) executes for users that are not logged in.
 wp_ajax_(action) executes for users that are  logged in.

you can use query response as you like.
Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful, will try adapt this to my function.